# How to convert a boolean expression to Binding<Bool> in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a textfield, and I am trying to goto another view when user input a specific string.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var whether_go = "No"
    var body: some View {
                    TextField("Goto?", text: $whether_go)
                        .navigate(to: CircleImage(), when: whether_go == "Yes")
    }
}
```

This will raise error: `Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'` Because `when` argument need a Binding<Bool>

I tried to use

```
when: Binding<Bool>(get: whether_happy == "Yes"))
```

This raise another error: `No exact matches in call to initializer.`

So what should I do to convert a boolean to Binding<Bool>?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use the `Binding(get:set:)` initialiser.

```
var body: some View {
        let binding = Binding<Bool>(get: { self.whether_go == "YES" }, set: { if $0 { self.whether_go = "YES"} else { self.whether_go = "NO" }})
        return TextField("Goto?", text: $whether_go)
                        .navigate(to: CircleImage(), when: binding)
    }
```

If you want the `Binding` to be 1-way, simply pass in an empty closure to `set`.

```
let binding = Binding<Bool>(get: { self.whether_go == "YES" }, set: { _ in })
```

Unrelated to your question, but why is `whether_go` a `String` and not a `Bool`? Also, you should follow Swift naming convention, which is lowerCamelCase for variable names (`whetherGo`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. ```whether_go``` is not the original variable name, I changed this name to make is comprehensible.