# Comparing An Object to Itself Returning False

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a class that implements the Equatable protocol, and it uses a UUID field for comparison:

```swift
class MemberViewModel {
    private static var entities: [MemberViewModel] = []
    private var entity: Member

    let id = UUID()

    init(_ entity: Member) {
        self.entity = entity
    }

    static func members() -> [MemberViewModel] {
        entities.removeAll()

        try? fetch().forEach { member in
            entities.append(MemberViewModel(member))
        }

        return entities
    }
}

extension MemberViewModel: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: MemberViewModel, rhs: MemberViewModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

I then have a view that creates icons that when tapped should display a stroke to denote it was "selected":

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @State var selectedMember: MemberViewModel? = nil

    var body: some View {
        let members = MemberViewModel.members()

        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true) {
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 4) {
                ForEach (members, id: \.id) { member in
                    var isSelected: Bool = selectedMember == member

                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color(.red))
                        .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                        .overlay() {
                            if isSelected {
                                Circle()
                                    .stroke(Color(.black), lineWidth: 2)
                            }
                        }
                        .onTapGesture { selectedMember = member }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried setting `isSelected` multiple ways, including the following from [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64044232/how-to-convert-a-boolean-expression-to-bindingbool-in-swiftui):

```swift
let isSelected = Binding<Bool>(get: { self.selectedMember == member }, set: { _ in })
```

When debugging using breakpoints, the value of `isSelected` is always false.

I'm using XCode Version 14.0.1 (14A400), and Swift 5.7.

Comment: Take a look at how Picker implemented `https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/picker` you will get much more ideas

Comment: I suspect you have a typo in `MemberViewModel`, you probably
 wanted `static var entities: [Member] = []` and similarly in
 `static func members() -> [Member]`.
 Currently you have a `MemberViewModel` that contains an array of `MemberViewModel`
 that contains an array of `MemberViewModel`, that contains.....etc..,etc...
 Make the `extension Member: Equatable {...}`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I'm not sure what that has to do with comparing the `selectedMember` to `member`, given that the `Equatable` is using the `UUID` that is defined in `MemberViewModel`, but it is by design that I am abstracting away access to the `Member` object.

Comment: My point was, re-structure your code.
 But suit yourself, use the `strange` one you have.

Comment: What is `selectedMember` at the point where you do the comparison? I wonder if the fact that it is a property wrapped variable is screwing it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `let members = MemberViewModel.members()` just before
`var body: some View {...}`, not inside it, like this:

```
let members = MemberViewModel.members()  // <-- here 

var body: some View {
  ...
}
```

Due to your weird code structure, `let members = MemberViewModel.members()`
gets re-done evey time the `body` is refreshed. And since the UUID is re-generated .... you can guess that the ids now are all over the place and not equal to the `selectedMember`.

In other words, the object comparison is working, but you are not comparing what you think.

Comment: Thank you. The body updating and regenerating the UUIDs never occurred to me, but moving the call outside of the body did the trick. Slava Ukraini!

Answer (score 0):

Use the sample below hope you get the idea.

### Model

```
struct Member {
    
    let id = UUID()
    
}

extension Member: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Member, rhs: Member) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

class MemberViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // each time you update the entities, view vill be updated
    @Published var entities: [Member] = []
    
    func fetchMembers() {
        entities.removeAll()

        // your code to fetch members
        try? fetch().forEach { member in
           entities.append(member)
        }
        
    }
}
```

### MyView

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var modelData = MemberViewModel()
    @State private var selectedMember: Member? = nil

    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true) {
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 4) {
                ForEach (modelData.entities, id: \.id) { member in

                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color(.red))
                        .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                        .overlay() {
                            if selectedMember == member {
                                Circle()
                                    .stroke(Color(.black), lineWidth: 2)
                            }
                        }
                        .onTapGesture { selectedMember = member }
                }
            }
        }.onAppear {
            modelData.fetchMembers()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer needs some text to explain what is going on.